# When the Keyboard opens the text field in the alert dialogue gets hide

Tags: flutter

I have created alert dialogue shows while pressing a button. In the alert dialogue there is an text field and which gets hide when the  keyboard gets open.I added code snippet below.

The output in Landscape view:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgDvP.png)

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: _MyAppState(),
        );
      }
    }
    class _MyAppState extends StatelessWidget {
      TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
    
      _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: true,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('AlertDialog with TextField'),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _textFieldController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "ENTER A TEXT",
                    ),
                    autofocus: true,
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('SUBMIT'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('AlertDialog with TextField '),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Show Alert Dialogue',
                ),
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                onPressed: () => _displayDialog(context),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove singlechildscriollview and wrap textfield inside container with some height. When you put scroll item in alert box, keyboard open may be create problems in some cases.

```
   showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('AlertDialog with TextField'),
            content: Container(
              height: 35,  
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textFieldController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "ENTER A TEXT",
                ),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('SUBMIT'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
```